# Seemingly defective paragraph regarding template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Omitting a template argument is possible, since the standard says in 17.9.1, paragraph 3 [temp.arg.explicit] ([N4700](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4700.pdf)):

> Trailing template arguments that can be deduced or obtained from default *template-argument*s may be omitted from the list of explicit *template-argument*s...

On the other hand, the standard has a conflicting rule, as 17.9.2, paragraph 2 [temp.deduct] shows (emphasis mine):

> ... Specifically, the following steps are performed when evaluating an explicitly specified template argument list with respect to a given function template:
>
> - If the specified template arguments do not match the template parameters in kind (i.e., type, non-type, template), or if there are more arguments than there are parameters and no parameter is a template parameter pack, **or if there is not an argument for each non-pack parameter,** type deduction fails.
> - ...

This paragraph suggests that all template arguments shall be specified if we were to use a explicit template argument list, which clearly contradicts to the above paragraph. Then, what's the intention?

Answer (score 5):

The second quote applies *"when evaluating an explicitly specified template argument list"*, but the first clearly is about the case when some template arguments are not explicitly specified.  There's no conflict, because they're talking about two different situations.

Comment: Do you see the second quote as having all template arguments explicitly specified? Then, I don't understand what's the point of stating the case where some arguments are not there (the one that I emphasized).

Comment: @b1sub Your emphasis makes following code ill-formed: `template<class, class> void foo() {} foo<void>();`

Comment: @Rakete1111 You're saying the case where an omitted template argument cannot be deduced. Am I right? If that's the case, I think that the standard should have added more contexts, rather than just referring to all the cases where a template argument is not present.

Comment: @b1sub Yes, but I don't understand your point, the standard is pretty clear here IMO. It says: Some types in the template parameter list can be deduced or known using the default argument. Then: If not all types of the template are known, the code is ill-formed. Note that it doesn't say *where* the arguments come from.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Since the paragraph starts with "when evaluating **an explicitly specified template argument list**" (clearly confining the whereabout), I thought that I should decide based exclusively on it. However, I see your points.

Comment: @b1sub It's just when the rules apply. If you look at your emphasis, there is no mention that the types have to come from the template parameter list.

Comment: @Rakete1111 He means this check shouldn't be performed so early, I think.